# can rails send data to browser chunk by chunk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very large dataset (100,000) to be display, but any browser I tried that on including chrome 5 dev, it make them choke for dozens of seconds (win7 64bit, 4gb, 256gb ssd, c2duo 2.4ghertz). I did a little experiment by

## some_controller.rb

def show
 @data = (1..100000).to_a
end

## show.html.erb

as simple as that it chokes the browsers. I know browsers were never built for this, so I thought to let the data come in chunk by chunk, I guess 2000 per chunk is reasonable, but I wouldn't want to make 50 requests each time this view is called, any ideas? It doesn't have to be chunk by chunk if it can be sent all at once.

Best,

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where showing 100,000 rows of data on one page would be useful to a user. Why not give the user ways to filter the data to what's relevant to them?

Comment: I know, but this is linguistic project that does demand having all these bits of data all at once, the detail is little complicated and out of scope here, but I appreciate your reminder of serving only what's relevant to get better performance.

Comment: Another thing to do is try to reduce the amount of markup you have as much as possible. Having a smaller DOM will reduce the load on the browser.

Comment: @Jordan, Yup, I am doing that as well. just <span id=>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did see a plugin that allowed this sort of thing, but I can't remember what it was called .... will keep trawling my notes.

In the meantime, this is what pagination is for :p

If you use-case doesn't support that, perhaps using AJAX would streamline things ... can use AJAX to load out the data incrementally, either as the user scrolls or automatically.

**UPDATE:** found the template streaming plugin: http://github.com/oggy/template_streaming

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, I watched Ryan Bates's "Endless Page" episodes, too. -- I will have to test out how much my server can handle if the ajax requests become too much...

Comment: With that many records, your server is probably already spending significant time rendering. Some judicious AJAX can actually reduce load as you can have smaller requests that complete in less time (and can be themselves cacheable). There will be a sweet spot between too many small requests and too few large ones ... best advice is to measure and see.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, I am sort of counting on this after having used Google Reader for a couple of years now. I am guess with 100,000 records, perhaps 1000 ~ 2000 each request wouldn't be so bad, i.e., 100 ~ 50 requests per loading.

Just out of curiousity, there aren't any compression mechanism on server side that can be used to compress these html output then let the browser decompress it, right?

Comment: Gzip - you can setup your server to gzip the output. Handled at the server level, which means no impact on your rails app.

Comment: Thanks Toby, I'll look into Gzip then.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to use render, passing it a proc.  The snippet of code below is from the Rails documentation.

```
# Streams about 180 MB of generated data to the browser.
render :text => proc { |response, output|
  10_000_000.times do |i|
    output.write("This is line #{i}\n")
    output.flush
  end
}
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000658

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason, this actually cause firefox to crash (the send report to mozilla thing came up), whereas my original method makes it go 'white-screened' but it comes back eventually.